# Deleted file won't go away with Maven, Eclipse, Git

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, struts2

I have a bizarre, enraging problem.  I have a Struts 2 application using Maven and Eclipse.  I have an action class and corresponding validation xml file in the package like so:

```
com / this / wont / work / RequestAction.java
                           RequestAction-validation.xml
```

I decided to delete RequestAction-validation.xml and use the annotations for validation instead.  But after I delete it from `src/main/java` and do a clean install in Maven, the RequestAction-validation.xml is still there in the WAR in my `target` directory!  I can't get rid of it!  I have no idea where it's coming from.  No matter how many times I clean the Maven project or clean the Eclipse project it's still there in `target` and therefore my web app is stuck using the xml validation.

Even if I delete `target` and run `mvn clean install` again, the old XML file still appears under `target/MyWAR.war/WEB-INF/classes`.  Strangely, the files in `target/classes` are correct - no XML file!  But the WAR is what is getting deployed.

I am using Git for source control and even if I commit and push the change for deleting the XML file, it still appears in `target/MyWAR.war`.  I can't find anywhere online that people have described this problem or a solution, so I am welcome to suggestions for how to get rid of this rogue XML file.  Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, is the file generated if you first delete `target/` then run `mvn clean install` again?

Comment: I guess that Maven or Eclipse have some feature that automatically creates the XML file during compilation.

Comment: Yes, the file is still generated - but your question caused me find something else, and I've edited my question with new info.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unknown to me, there were files present in my local repo project under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes`.  I'm not sure how that folder got there.  There was an old `RequestAction-validation.xml` file in that directory (along with other undesired files) and that must have been copied to the WAR.
I've deleted `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes` and that has solved it!